# how to display the data in tableviewsection using mvvm

Tags: ios

I have  problem while creating the model.

My api is in such way.

```
{data:["name":"seena","option":["Yes, always","no"]]}
```

so according to this i need to display the data in tableviewsection using mvvm way.

Here i need two create two model 
1.for question list 
2.options list

mymodel:-

```
class QuestionListModel: NSObject {

    var home:[OPTIONS] = []

    var id:Int!
    var question:String!
    var options:[String]?
    var v:String?



    init(dictionary :JSONDictionary) {

        guard   let question = dictionary["question"] as? String,
                let id = dictionary["id"] as? Int
             else {
                return

        }




        if let options = dictionary["options"] as? [String]{
            print(options)

           print(options)


        }


        self.question = question
        self.id = id
                }

}
```

in viewmodel:-

```
  func numberOfSections(tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
        print((datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)!)
        return (datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)!
    }

    func titleForHeaderInSection(atsection section: Int) -> QuestionListModel {
        return datasourceModel.dataListArray![section]
    }


    func numberOfRowsInSection(section:Int) -> Int {
        print(self.tableArray[section].count)
        return self.tableArray[section].count
    }
```

and in the viewcontroller as:-

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return reviewViewModel.numberOfSections(tableView: tableView)
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {


      //  let headercell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HeaderCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! questionheader


        let identifier = "HeaderCell"

        var headercell: questionheader! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? questionheader

        if headercell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "questionheader", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            headercell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? questionheader
        }

        headercell.setReviewData(reviews:reviewViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection:section))




        return headercell
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 63

    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // 2
        //return 1

        return reviewViewModel.numberOfRowsInSection(section: section)
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let identifier = "Cell"
        var cell: QuestionListCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? NH_QuestionListCell

        if cell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "NH_QuestionListCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? QuestionListCell
        }
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear


        print(reviewViewModel.tableArray)

        if (reviewViewModel.type == "1"){


            cell.imagebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_uncheck.png"), for: .normal)

        }
        else{


            cell.imagebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_uncheck.png"), for: .normal)
        }


       if let tempArray = reviewViewModel.tableArray[indexPath.section] as? [String] {

        print(tempArray)

        let values = tempArray[indexPath.row]




        print(values)
        cell.question.text = values


        }

        return cell
         }
```

And how to display data of options in tableviewcell

Comment: how to solve the problem?

Comment: What did you try so far? I would like to make it a bit more clear to you that stackoverflow community doesn't solve the problems instead of you. It helps you correct or direct you in the right way. It seems that you just posted a task here, and you would like to get the whole answer without doing any effort.

Comment: i have updated my code.but here i need to create other model for options from that i need the noofsections and datafordisplay in tableview?HOW TO CREATE IT?

Comment: @OlegDanu i have updated mycode please check.

Comment: See in MVVM your viewmodel will have data to work on and provide it to the VC's views. In your case your custom cell class can have a method like setCellData(yourModel) to set its values. And in the cell method you populate your data on the cell.

Comment: @vivekDas here how to create the model?

Comment: In your viewmodel you have datasourceModel object right, create a method in your viewmodel cellDataForIndex(index: Int), this will return datasourceModel.dataListArray[index], now pass this object to your cell class method to show data

Comment: @can u please give the function in viewmodel and viewcontroller cellforrow in tableview